# Custom Android Spinner Layout Issue

Tags: java, android, xml, spinner

I am customizing an android Spinner Widget. I am trying to use different background colors against the list items. This is working, but when there are more items in the spinner control, the list items are not occupying the full space horizontally, thus showing white space on the popup view.

For small number of items, it is working fine.

I have tried custom and default Layout customizations.

JAVA Custom Spinner View Code

```
            @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            LayoutInflater objInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            view                       = objInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item_colored, null);


            LinearLayout llOption = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llOption);
            TextView tvOption     = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvOption);


            if (alDefects.get(pos).sNature.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                llOption.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.majorDefect));

            else if (alDefects.get(pos).sNature.equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
                llOption.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.criticalDefect));

            else
                llOption.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.minorDefect));


            tvOption.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            tvOption.setText(alDefects.get(pos).sDefect);

            return view;
        }
```

XML Code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/llOption"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvOption"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="#444444"
    android:textSize="13dp" />
```

I want the spinner popup to use full available width for Background color when there is a scrollbar.

[Please click this Link to see the Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6fLj.png)

Comment: Also the spinner popup is loaded fine but then within a second, the layout is refreshed to wrap the width as per item text.

Answer (score 0):

When you use weight you should set   `android:layout_width="0dp"`

Comment: I have also tried that but no difference in output.

Comment: try set layout width for textview and LinearLayout programmatically using layout params

Comment: LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


tvOption.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

Comment: No luck with these also. As stated, the spinner popup is loaded correctly but right after load, the layout is disturbed.